Failed to start LSB: TACACS+ server ... TAC_PLUS 4.0.4.26 installed on Centos Stream 9
I'm trying to install TACACS+ on a Fresh Install of Centos 9.  I've worked through a number of errors, but I am currently stuck. Here is the output of journalctl;
Nov 07 16:17:27 ENNVCENTAC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: TACACS+ server based on Cisco source release...
Nov 07 17:06:37 ENNVCENTAC tac_plus[4023]: Starting tacacs+:
Nov 07 17:06:37 ENNVCENTAC tac_plus[4024]: Usage: tacacs {start|stop|status|restart|reload}
Nov 07 17:06:37 ENNVCENTAC systemd[1]: tac_plus.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 07 17:06:37 ENNVCENTAC systemd[1]: tac_plus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit tac_plus.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 17:06:37 ENNVCENTAC systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: TACACS+ server based on Cisco source release.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit tac_plus.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried several command line variations to start the service

this is more of a sysadmin problem than a programming one, you may have more luck on the nix stack: https://unix.stackexchange.com/
